# LoRa32 error to display BMP180 DATA

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp32, lorawan

I want to show the *BMP180* data using an *ESP32 LoRa*, but I am receiving this error. Any help will be appreciate:

> OLED_LoRa_Sender:113: error: no matching function for call to 
>   'SSD1306Wire::drawString(float)'
>
> display.drawString(bmp.readTemperature());

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this error because the `readTemperature()` method returns a float and the `drawString()` method doesn't take a float as its argument.

You need to call methods like `drawString()` with the arguments they expect to take or your code won't compile (or if it does somehow compile it won't run correctly).

You can usually find this in documentation for the library you're using or in the source code - look in the `.h` header files.

You didn't say which library you're using, but if it's the one at https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306 then you can find the declaration of `drawString()` [here](https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306/blob/e2286ba37b4454fd2e0e22697a522ac222ffadbc/src/OLEDDisplay.h#L180).

`void drawString(int16_t x, int16_t y, String text);`

In order to successfully call `drawString()` you'll need to pass it `x` and `y` coordinates and a String object, not a float, like so:

`display.drawString(5, 10, String(bmp.readTemperature()));`

This should draw the string at coordinates (5, 10) on the display.